# angular expression in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am using the angular expression as value in textbox to perform some operation

```
             `<tr>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.costPrice" required
                                placeholder=" product Cost" class="form-  control" > <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Profit</label></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="Product.profit" required
                                placeholder=" Profit in %" class="form-control"> <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>price</label></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="text"  value="{{product.costPrice * Product.profit}}" ng-model="Product.sellingPrice" required
                                placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control"> <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>

                        <p>Expense on Books : {{product.costPrice * Product.profit}} Rs</p>
                        </td>
                        </tr>`
```

the expression is not working at all even though its working in the `<p></p>` tag what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Where you mentioned your controller and provide code of controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function (inside the function you can write and return your expression):

```
$scope.myExpression = function(){
    return $scope.myVar + "hello";//this is your expression function
}
```

and call it from input box like this using `ng-value`

```
<input ng-value="myExpression()">
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vB5z4eWzsjKHtFVM05cA?p=preview)

Comment: your answer is pretty conviencing but i don't understand why my in my case ng-value is not able to populate the value ; <input type="text" ng-value="myExpression()" ng-model="Product.sellingPrice" required
placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control"> <span class="help-block"></span></td>   here is the controller code angular.module('sbAdminApp').controller('smsCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout,$http,$state) {
    $scope.cancel=function()
   {
 $state.go('dashboard.home');
}    $scope.Product={};
   $scope.myExpression = function(){
    return $scope.Product.name + "hello";
     }

Comment: you should not give ng-model and ng-value both..it does not make sense.should be like this:
`<input type="text" ng-value="myExpression()" required placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control"> `

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function will help to compute for you and then provide the result to your scope. ng-model will bind it for you. ng-value can be easily avoided in this case.

```
$scope.calculate = function(cost, profit) {
    $scope.Product.sellingPrice = cost * profit;
  }
```

And this will simply give you the result in your textbox

```
<input ng-model="Product.sellingPrice">
```

[See demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3saIOOaYtVeXxIWqsJd1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

**value="{{product.costPrice * Product.profit}}" ng-model="Product.sellingPrice"**

with

**ng-model="Product.sellingPrice=product.costPrice * Product.profit"**

in the following line:

```
<input type="text"  value="{{product.costPrice * Product.profit}}" ng-model="Product.sellingPrice" required placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control">
```

Working code : http://plnkr.co/edit/YLQZaCKPsLrk0QN3hvnU?p=preview

Comment: then how can i access this textbox in the controller ??

Comment: by accessing Product.sellingPrice

Comment: the ng-model of the input is still "Product.sellingPrice",I am just evaluating the value of "product.costPrice * Product.profit" into "Product.sellingPrice" by writing it within ng-model itself.

Comment: i dont think this way is workable as its throwing error

Comment: Show me your updated code,I ran the code,and it worked fine.

Comment: <input type="text"  ng-model="Product.sellingPrice = Product.costPrice * Product.profit" required placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control"> and here is the error message Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ngModel/nonassign?p0=Product.sellingPric…something .....

Comment: finf working code here http://plnkr.co/edit/YLQZaCKPsLrk0QN3hvnU?p=preview

Comment: You forgot to assign controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can do calculation in controller..
or else try this...

```
       <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.costPrice" required
                                placeholder=" product Cost" class="form-  control" > <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Profit</label></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="Product.profit" required
                                placeholder=" Profit in %" class="form-control"> <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>price</label></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="Product.sellingPrice" required
                                placeholder=" selling price" class="form-control"> <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>

                        <p>Expense on Books : {{Product.sellingPrice = product.costPrice * Product.profit}} Rs</p>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
```